# Getting 502 error with servicestack memory server events (IIS 8)

Tags: c#, azure, servicestack, iis-8, server-sent-events

I have a servicestack API project hosted on Azure portal, which has memory server events enabled. I just NotifyAll on some event POST. Clients would read the notifications from /event-stream?channel=''. I set time out for 6 hours. Performed tests for 4 hours with frequent gap between posts. It looked really good and worked perfectly fine when I test it locally.

After its hosted on Azure, I POST events and clients receive notifications but not for long. We start receiving 502 error in random. There is no detail or subtype of this error ([i.e if its is a 502.1 or 502.2 or 502.3 or 502.4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891)? Not sure). After this error, unless we refresh the event-stream API we will not receive notification on further POSTs. Users who refresh this API, will continue to receive notification. 502 error is possible to occur again and the same repeats

I tried disabling server events to see if I still receive 502, but no. It is clearly something to do with server events.

My website is hosted as single instance (hence Redis server events are not required I guess) and it uses IIS8 and 4.5 framework.

I hope I provided all necessary information to analyse this issue. If not please let me know. It would be great if someone could help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Ultimately the 5xx errors are server errors, so I'd point the finger at either IIS or Azure configuration. (I will add the IIS tag.)

Comment: 502 errors is a Bad Gateway error which is usually reported by a middleware proxy about a downstream error. But this doesn't say anything about what the downstream error is, so you'll need to try find the root cause of the error, first by looking at the HTTP Error Response Headers to see if that has any info otherwise by looking through log files for any reported exceptions.

Comment: @Darren cook. Thank you for your quick response..  I don't understand what do you mean by add the IIS tag.. Can you please elaborate a bit Also I would like to let you know that interaction between Azure environment/IIS with service stack results in 502 error. This is not the case when I remove Server events from my application(which is still hosted on same environment) and POST events

Comment: @mythz thank you.. I tried to explore on the issue but it doesn't give me more information so am not sure of the root cause. Also as I told you, this is random. I get this within first 100 event POSTs. I am still probing into it looking for hint. Will publish here if any

Comment: @Vinu, by "add the IIS tag" I mean I edited your question to add "IIS-8" as a tag. This increases the chance that someone who specializes in IIS questions might get to see your question.

Comment: @Vinu SSE holds open a socket, which are a limited resource on servers. (There is also more memory being used.) So it is quite possible that some server-side configuration, such as MaxConnections, is causing the issue, but is only seen when you run with SSE on.  (I don't know IIS/Azure well enough to be sure, I'm just saying it fits the evidence so far.)

Comment: Ah right.. Thank you Darren..